# A common error in OpenCV Mat accessing & using Mat_

Tags: opencv, matrix

I used the following code to access to Mat's elements and found this difficulty: 
[image]

2 problems arise here:

- nzpxl Mat is hard-defined the type CV_16UC2 or it is passed in from this function's caller
- nzpxl is accessed by at which is also a hard form

So, when there isn't a good correspondence between the two, the function crashes. I hardly know which are even compatible. For example, does CV_16UC2 correspond with Vec2i ??

**Question 1**: Can this only be hard coded?
**Question 2**: How to know the compatible types?

Edit 01: 
Sorry for lack of information! About Mat_ template, I've seen posts using Mat_ to define their own type for clarity and avoid using `OpenCV` default types. Is this one answer to my 2nd question?

Comment: I don't see anything here that would be a **bug**. You probably should change your question title, or at least describe what you think is a **bug** in your text.

Comment: I mean that's a programming bug, not OPenCV bug. Is it misleading?? here, becasue Vec2i doens't work with CV_16UC2 or something, my program crashes right at the Mat access command i.e. nzpx.at<Vec2i> ..

Comment: Yes, it's misleading. *Bug* generally refers to a problem in the library/OS or whatever; *error* generally refers to something you're doing wrong yourself. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a moment where you have to decide what kind of data you are storing in your matrix, and this has to be "hard-coded" somewhere.

If you decide that your data matrix is of type CV_16UC2, then you should check in all functions that access pixels in this matrix (e.g. using at<>) that the matrix is in the expected form:

```
void someFunction(cv::Mat &myMatrixOf16UC2) {
  // using asserts
  assert(myMatrixOf16UC2.type() == CV_16UC2);
  // or using exceptions
  if (myMatrixOf16UC2.type() != CV_16UC2)
    throw  someException;


  // do the job
```

}

By the way, int are 32 bits, so Vec2i should deal with matrices allocated with CV_32SC2.
CV_16UC2 -> cv::Vec2s, or even cv::Vec for which there is no predefined typedefs in OpenCV.

One useful pratice is to define somewhere for your program the data you are using with a typedef and a corresponding type() function, e.g. in a header:

```
 typedef cv::Vec<unsigned short, 2> pixel_t;
```

and

```
 int getOpenCVTypeForMyPixelType() { return CV_16UC2; }
```

Then if you want to change from short to int or float, you just have to modify those functions

Comment: then, with the func getOPenCVTypeFor..., I will not have to remember the correspondence between Vec<unsigned short, 2> and CV_16UC2, right?? BUt with this, this compatibility must be known beforehand and I'm still having troubles to figure it out. May be from your answer, I can learn the way to have this information.

Comment: about the hard coding of type, I dont' really agree. for example, if I want my func to work on 2 types integer and float, would I have to replicate the 2 accessing commands for these 2 types?? says matrix.at<integer>... and matrix.at<float>... the code will look ugly, right?? along with a 'case' or 'if' statement

Comment: Well, cv::Mat just stores the data as an array of unsigned char, so you have to get a way to get your data in the appropriate type. You can use template Mat_<T> wrapper to avoid calling to at<T>(), but they do exactly the same. See [documentation for Mat_](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#id5)